# python 2.4 and python 2.7 path conflict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I try to install python 2.7 on centos which has 2.4 on it.
I have read many documents and try to apply them but there are still many conflicts.
I am a user with sudo grant.
When I write python, it runs python 2.7.1 from the location /opt/python2.7.1/bin however, when I try to install setuptools as `python setup.py install` it is installed under `/usr/local/bin`.

What can be the problem? Shouldn't it be in /opt/python2.7.1./bin ?

Note: I have updated my .bash_profile

Comment: You might have installed for 2.4.  One simple trick is to `alias python=python2.7` which will invoke 2.7 when you type `python`.

Comment: When you install Python 2.7, by default, it becomes the system-default `python`. To prevent that from happening, install it with `altinstall` instead of `install`. Then again, I may have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple versions of Python installed you must then also specify the version you want when you invoke it. On CentOS the default Python is 2.4, and is named just "python". So when you install with "python ..." you will be running with 2.4, and it will try to install in the 2.4 site-packages directory. In order to get it installed for 2.7 you must use "python2.7 ..." to install.

Python uses built-in variables to determine where it lives and installs things. What is the output of:

```
python2.7 -c "import sys; print sys.prefix"
```

Comment: It gives '/usr/local/'. What should it be and how can I fix this?

Comment: IT can be /usr/local. Just make sure /usr/local/bin is on your PATH. Python2.7 will install setup.py packages into /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.